# Why can't I set this to a string?

Tags: objective-c

I've just starting out with obj-c and I created 2 files, a .h and a .m file. The .h file is..

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CardUnit : NSObject
{

@property (assign) NSString *name;
@property (assign) NSString *gold;
@end
```

and the .m file is

```
#import "CardUnit.h"

@implementation CardUnit

@synthesize gold  = @"gold";
@synthesize name = _name;

@end
```

But it's giving me an error on

```
@synthesize gold  = @"gold";
```

Saying "expected ; after synthesize"

Why can't I set that to a string?

Comment: The opening brace (`{`) in your interface declaration is unmatched as well but braces are not needed if you have no ivars.  Just fyi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@synthesize` is not used for giving variables a value, but is rather a shorthand for defining basic getters and setters for the variable. The

```
@synthesize var = _var
```

syntax is used to say, "I want you to use the instance variable `_var` as the internal variable for the property `var`".

If you want to assign a default string to a property, put it in your `init` method:

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString*)name
{
  self = [super init];
  if(self)
  {
    self.gold = @"gold";
    self.name = name
  }
  return self;
}
```

Or you can set the default value in the getter (per @Mario's comment bellow):

```
-(NSString*)gold 
{
  _gold ? return _gold : return @"gold";
}
```

Comment: Or put default value in your getter. E.g. if (!gold) return @"gold";

Answer (score 2):

You got `synthesize` wrong. It is not for assigning values, it is for generating default setter/getter methods in case you do not provide them. You can use `property = ivar` to specify which ivar should be used for the property, but a constant value is NOT ivar. So you can't assign string value in this way. Please check [The Obj-C Programming Language (Property Implementation Directives)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW13) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign a value in the @synthesize declaration.

The @synthesize is a declaration that sets getters and setters for variables. and it is not for assigning vales.

You should do later on in a method that will set the value to your "gold" var.

Comment: I'm an AS3 dev, so I'm used to be able to set my vars outside of methods, can you not do that in obj-c?

Comment: @Phil No, Objective-C ivars are always set to 0 upon creation. You can't set them to a default value except in code. You'd usually set the default values in your class's `-init` method. Also, you should really make your property `retain` or `copy` if you're not using ARC and `strong` or `copy` if you are. `assign` will cause memory issues with objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are not suppose to set value to the variable in synthesize. They are just for synthesize accessor methods.

Answer (score 0):

The `@synthesize` generates a getter and setter for the property, but the compiler takes care of generating those.

I think it would be a good idea to read a good tutorial on iOS development, maybe start with the [Start developing iOS apps today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) on the Apple Developer connection website.